# Помогите запустить сервис (телеграм бот на питоне) на debian 11

Tags: python, telegram-bot, debian

Подскажите пожалуйста, вроде сделал всё как в интернете говорят, но не запускается. Вот сам сервис:

```
[Unit]
Description=VPNManager
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/root/VPNmanager-env/venv/bin/python /root/VPNmanager.py
PIDFile=/root/VPNmanager.pid
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Кажется, что не запускается из-за запуска из виртуального окружения. В скрипте стоит шибанг

```
#!/root/VPNmanager-env/bin python
```

Если запускать скрипт из виртуального окружения, то работает всё норм.

Ругается на строчку ExecStart с ошибкой:

```
(code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в строчке PIDFile=/root/VPNmanager.pid, файла не было и я думал он сгенерируется сам. Удалил строчку и всё запустилось.